# Exporting workflow templates

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there any way to export workflow templates (and then import them into another CRM)?  I exported all my workflows, but the templates were not among them. I'm not seeing how this is done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no direct way to export a Workflow template. In order to export it, you will have to turn it into a regular Workflow. After importing in the destination CRM, you can edit it and change it back to a template before publishing.

Would this be an acceptable workaround in your scenary?